# Update SQL Server table with one time use values from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of users that has the usual suspects, name, email, etc. As the users complete an activity (queried from another table), I need to award them a gift card code.

```
update users   
set giftcardcode = 'code from other table' 
where email in (select email from useractivity where necessary conditions are met)
```

I have a table of unique gift card codes that are unique, one-time use codes. So I need to update my user table, setting the award code field equal to a distinct, unused gift card code from the gift card code table. Then I need to mark the 'used' field in the gift card table to 'Y'.

The goal is to do this with SQL and not any programming. I'm stumped.

Comment: does sql script count as programming?

Comment: If it can be done inside SQL server, that's fine. I'm just looking for a solution that won't cause me to have to write a script in another language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a Many To Many relationship between User table and Activity table.

So, you can use a trigger to execute a query when update.
Each time a row will be updated in the Activity table, the trigger will do something.
It will UPDATE the User table by adding a new gift code.

I think you can add an attribute in your GiftCode table to easily check if the code as already been used. An you can get an unused code like that :

```
// Retrieve an unused code based on a BIT attribute.
SELECT TOP 1 [Code] FROM [GiftCode] WHERE IS_UNUSED = 1;
```

Don't forget to update this Gift code after using it.

You can use a SELECT statement including a sub SELECT statement to get a code too :

```
// Retrieve an unused code based on User table used codes.
SELECT TOP 1 [Code] FROM [GiftCode] WHERE [Code] NOT IN (SELECT [Code] FROM [User]);
```

It works well if you don't have too much users.
Otherwise , the first statement will be more efficient.
Don't forget to update the User table.

Now you can easily use one of these previous statement in a UPDATE statement.
It will be something like that :

```
UPDATE [User] SET [Code] = (
    SELECT TOP 1 [Code] FROM [GiftCode] WHERE [Code] NOT IN (
        SELECT [Code] FROM [User]))
WHERE USER_ID = // ...;
```

You can perform this in a trigger.

You can use a [stored procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345415.aspx), it's more efficient and will wrap all the SQL code in a compiled function. Then you can call it in your trigger.
You can execute a stored procedure in a job (see SQL Server Agent jobs) too.

Comment: I am working through this solution. One thing I should have mentioned, these tables aren't being updated live. The data is exported from the system and imported into my db. I need to loop through - for each person that meets the requirements, assign a code... I'm not sure a trigger will accomplish this. Can I just execute a SP multiple times?

Comment: Yes you can. You can create a stored procedure with a loop too. If you don't want to update in live, you can execute a stored procedure in a scheduled task. I think a SP is the best way and the most easy to customize because you create a function with parameters, loops, ...or more.

Answer (score 0):

create a **Trigger** on your table for **update** and do what you want inside it using **inserted** and **deleted**

Comment: apparently all the OP asks is Update